# What is the meaning of "back" in "will even reverse-engineer from the metadata and IL code back into C# for you"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> [The **Go to Definition** function] will show what the public definition of the type or member looks like by reading the metadata in the compiled assembly.  Some tools, such as ILSpy .NET Decompiler, will even
> reverse-engineer from the metadata and IL code **back** into C# for you.

[C# 9 and .NET 5 – Modern Cross-Platform Development](https://books.google.com/books?id=00EIEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA23&lpg=PA23&dq=%22Some+tools,+such+as+ILSpy+.NET+Decompiler,+will+even+reverse-engineer+from+the+metadata%22&source=bl&ots=Am1Nap84Ao&sig=ACfU3U3lAWYW8LiIFgbS80nfuFlmtywwKA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjihOWymJPzAhWjFDQIHUb7B8kQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22Some%20tools%2C%20such%20as%20ILSpy%20.NET%20Decompiler%2C%20will%20even%20reverse-engineer%20from%20the%20metadata%22&f=false)

First of all, I would say that **C#** is a a programming language.
Why does it say: "back" into C#? Does it mean that: there are some tools that return some data for you by the c# language?

Comment: This will be clearer if you include the preceding sentence in the quotation.  I'll go ahead and edit that in for you.

Answer (score 2):

Programs are written in a programming language, like C#, and then a compiler turns them into [*object code*](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/546/object-code).

What this tool does is take the object code, and give you C# source code.  That is why the word **back** is used: it was once C#, then it was object code, and now it has returned to C# again.

Comment: The context mentions "assembly", so it's probably assembly code rather than object code.  But otherwise I agree with this answer.

Comment: So  it Doesn't mean "It return the metadata by c#", It means that "it give me c# codes", am I right?

Comment: Right, it means "it gives you C#".  It *uses* the metadata to do that.